# Pacejs: Start the minify loader when it enters a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to start the pace loader on when it enters a function and complete it when it exits the same function.

I used the below code, which is not starting the loader.

```
pace.start();
```

Comment: @ Kiran Kumar what does you `console` says?, have find anything there?

Comment: @ozil: Am trying to get this in a long manipulated function which not a AJAX call....

Answer (score 0):

Have you included these

```
<script src="../pace.js"></script>
<link href="../themes/pace-theme-corner-indicator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Yes I have included these